# golang: sort.Search can't find first element in a slice

Tags: go

I have write some code to find element position in sorted slice use sort.Search, but it can't correctly get the right position of first element.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    data := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool {
        return data[i] < 2 // or data[i] == 1
    }))
}
```

The standard output is always 3 rather than 0.
Is it a bug? Or am i wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search for the first element, then in your comparator function you should compare the `i`<sup>th</sup> element to the first which is `data[0]` (or the value which is `1`).

And since your slice is sorted in ascending order, you have to use the `>=` operator for comparision because `sort.Search()` returns the smallest index `i` in `[0, n)` at which `f(i)` is `true`.

```
data := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool {
    return data[i] >= data[0] // You could also use 1 instead of data[0]
}))
```

Output: `0` as expected. Try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/hFKjcv27_q).

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit difficult to understand, in my opinon, there is no different between to these, but causes two different answers.

Comment: @cosiner Read the doc of [`sort.Search()`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search). It clearly states that if the collection is sorted in ascending order, `>=` have to be used, and if it is sorted in descending order, `<=` have to be used. So since you used `<` it certainly will not work.